# Software for editing HOSTS file in windows

Tags: hosts, hosts-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Editing the HOSTS file](https://superuser.com/questions/50601/editing-the-hosts-file)

Is there a software which allow you to nicely edit hosts file in Windows? For instance, it should allow searching, and will display information in tabulated form.

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but close enough.